# controling an img with screen.width

Tags: javascript, html, image

trying to make an img hit the left side of my screen and return to the right. going right to left is super easy but i cant seem to find the left side of my screen for a reference point. using screen.width
is there a way to get the left side of the screen? ive tried (screen.width-screen.width) and just guessing screen.width-1920
this is my code for right to left.

```
if(parseInt(el.style.left) > (screen.availWidth - 100))el.style.left = 0;
if(parseInt(el.style.top) > (screen.height))el.style.top = 0;
el.style.left = parseInt(el.style.left) + rn1 + 'px';
el.style.top = parseInt(el.style.top) + rn2 + 'px';
```

Comment: Does "hit the left side of my screen" mean that you want the left edge of the image exactly lined up to the left edge of the screen? The `.style.left` of an element is relative to its container and/or natural position in the flow of elements (depending on its `position` setting - `relative` or `absolute`, or...), not relative to the screen. *"ive tried (screen.width-screen.width)"* - Why would that calculation give you anything other than zero?

Comment: yes sorry left edge.

Comment: sorry for bad terminology. im just learning. your right about screen.width-screen.width not sure what i was thinking. the img is set to absolute. and im able to make the first img scroll across the screen moving to top if it hits bottom and moving back to the left side of the screen when it hits the right. now im trying to basicly do the opposite.

Comment: OK, but the absolute position still depends on the position setting of any containing objects. Can you show the relevant html/css, and/or provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://bwilliams.x10host.com/javaclass/hour15.html

Comment: i just realized the css file attached to that still has old numbers everything on #2 is reset to 0. going to re upload that now maybe get to it before u see it

Comment: [link]http://bwilliams.x10host.com/javaclass/hour15.html
[link]http://bwilliams.x10host.com/javaclass/hour15.js
[link]http://bwilliams.x10host.com/javaclass/hour15.css

Comment: i cant belive just putting 0 and switch > to < doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is taking the full width of the viewport, then what is stoppng you from using `float: left/right` to play with the image alignment.

Comment: ill look into using that, but i was originally following directions for a school project. most of the code was wrote out and i had to tweak it and make it hit the botton and go to the top. for extra i added in another img and was trying to make it go a different direction. trying to push my self and learn more. but failing

Answer (score 0):

If anyone cares it wasnt working because it wasnt giving a true px back. once i added + 'px' to the end of the if statement, was working like a charm